# Computing tangent space for quadric

Tags: manifolds

> What is the tangent space to the quadric $x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_{n-1}^2=x_n^2$ at the point $p=(1,0,\ldots,0,1)$?

The definition of a *tangent space* that I know is based on the fact that we have a manifold $X$, and then finding a map $f$ from a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $f$ is a submersion at all points of $V$.

But here, this quadric is [not a manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600534/quadric-in-n-dimensions-is-a-manifold). How can I compute its tangent space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tangent space to an algebraic variety $V$ defined by $f_1(X)=\dots=f_p(X)=0$ at a smooth point is the kernel of the Jacobian matrix of $(f_1,\ldots,f_p)$. A smooth point is a point of $V$ where the rank of the Jacobian matrix is equal to the codimension of $V$.

Here, the Jacobian matrix is $J(x_1,\ldots, x_n)=\begin{bmatrix} 2 x_1&\dots&2 x_{n-1}&-2 x_n\end{bmatrix}$.

At $p=(1,0,\ldots,0,1)$, we get
$J(p)=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 &\dots&0&-2\end{bmatrix}$.

The rank of $J(p)$ is equal to $1$, which is also also the codimension of your hypersurface so $p$ is indeed a smooth point of the quadric. Then the tangent space to your quadric at $p$ can be computed as the kernel of $J(p)$.